# Не могу обратиться к $store из компоненты vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, spa

Компонента:

```
      <a href="#" class="header-links__el">{{ $store.state.headerLinks.title }}</a>
</template>
```

store/index.js:

````
export const store = createStore({
    state: {
        headerLinks: [
            {id: 1, title: 'Главная'},
            {id: 2, title: 'Честная игра'},
            {id: 3, title: 'FAQ'},
            {id: 4, title: 'Поддержка'},
            {id: 5, title: 'Акции'}
        ]
},
    getters: {

    },
    mutations: {

    },
    actions: {

    },
    modules: {
    }
})```
main.js:
```import { createApp} from "vue";
import App from './App'

import { store } from "@/store";

const app = createApp(App)

app

        .use(store)
        .mount('#app')
````

[image: и выходит вот такая ошибка в вебшторме]

Comment: На всякий случай, vuex установлен? Что происходит при попытке запустить dev сервер? Не вижу у вас импортов для createStore() метода

Comment: `import { createApp} from "vue";
import App from './App'

import { store } from "@/store";

const app = createApp(App)

app

        .use(store)
        .mount('#app')
` установлен, импорт в main.js